# Server encountered an internal error,the exception is org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have written an cod ein eclipse IDE with Apache tomcat integrated in it.Its running fin ethere.But when I try to run it externally through Apache tomcat I get the following Error-

```
 `exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. comparision_list.Comaprision resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 15 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. ref_time.Ref_log_current resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

`
```

My jsp file which give error is-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page import="comparision_list.Comaprision"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ page import="ref_time.Ref_log_current" %>
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Reference</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="ref" class="comparision_list.Vacc_vs6"/>

<!-- 
<b>Filling_Reference</b>
<br>
<table border="0" >
<tr>

<td bgcolor="darkgray" height="5" width="15"></td>
<td><font><b>Reference_Color</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="cornsilk" height="5" width="15"></td>
<td><font><b>User_Selection_Color</b></font></td>
</tr>
</table> -->
<br>

  <%
//Comaprision obj = new Comaprision();
   String s_date= request.getParameter("startdate");
   pageContext.setAttribute("s_date", s_date);
   String e_date= request.getParameter("enddate");
   pageContext.setAttribute("e_date", e_date);
   ref.refarray_vac1(s_date,e_date);
   ref.ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User(s_date,e_date);

%>


<%
//Comaprision reference = new Comaprision();
   String ref_name= request.getParameter("ref_logtime");
   pageContext.setAttribute("ref_name", ref_name);
   ref.FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen(ref_name);
   ref.refernece(ref_name);

%>

<br><br><br>

 <table width = "170%" border = "1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <th>Date-Time</th>
     <th>beam_current</th>
     <th>beam_energy</th>
     <th>st4_vs6_bag1_rb</th>
     <th>st4_vs6_bag2_rb</th>
     <th>st4_vs6_bag3_rb</th>



   </tr>

 <c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />

<c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.refarray_vac1(param.startdate,param.enddate)}">
<c:forEach var="r" items="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}" begin="${count}" end="${count}"> 

<tr bgcolor="darkgray ">
<td><c:out value="${r.logtime}"></c:out></td>

<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(r.beam_current) ne 0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${r.beam_current}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" 

pattern="##.##" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${r.beam_current}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(r.beam_energy) ne 0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${r.beam_energy}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" 

pattern="##.##" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${r.beam_energy}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(r.st4_vs6_bag1_rb) > 0.0}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${r.st4_vs6_bag1_rb}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" 

pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="OFF"></c:out> </c:otherwise></c:choose></td>

<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(r.st4_vs6_bag2_rb) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${r.st4_vs6_bag2_rb}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" 

pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="OFF"></c:out></c:otherwise></c:choose></td>

<td><c:choose><c:when test="${(r.st4_vs6_bag3_rb) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${r.st4_vs6_bag3_rb}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" 

pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="OFF"></c:out></c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


</tr>

<!-- For user_selection color name-- darkkhaki -->

<tr bgcolor="cornsilk">

<td><c:out value="${row.logtime}"></c:out></td>

<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(row.beam_current) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${row.beam_current}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" 

pattern="##.##" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${row.beam_current}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(row.beam_energy) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${row.beam_energy}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" 

pattern="##.##" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${row.beam_energy}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(row.st4_vs6_bag1_rb) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${row.st4_vs6_bag1_rb}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" 

pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="OFF"></c:out></c:otherwise></c:choose></td>



<td>
<c:choose><c:when test="${(row.st4_vs6_bag2_rb) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${row.st4_vs6_bag2_rb}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" 

pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="OFF"></c:out></c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


<td><c:choose><c:when test="${(row.st4_vs6_bag3_rb) > 0.0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${row.st4_vs6_bag3_rb}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" 

pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:out value="OFF"></c:out></c:otherwise></c:choose></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Deviation</td>

<td scope="row" style="${r.beam_current-row.beam_current eq 0 ? 'background-color: 

lime':'background-color: pink'}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.beam_current-row.beam_current)}" maxFractionDigits="2" 

minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${(mm)}" ></c:out></td>


<td scope="row" style="${r.beam_energy-row.beam_energy eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-

color: pink'}">
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.beam_energy-row.beam_energy)}" maxFractionDigits="2" 

minIntegerDigits="2"  var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
<c:out value="${(mm)}" ></c:out></td>

<td style="${r.st4_vs6_bag1_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag1_rb eq 0 ? 'background-color: lime':'background-

color: pink'}">
<c:choose><c:when test="${((r.st4_vs6_bag1_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag1_rb)) ne 0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.st4_vs6_bag1_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag1_rb)}" maxFractionDigits="2" 

minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${(r.st4_vs6_bag1_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag1_rb)}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>


<td scope="row" style="${r.st4_vs6_bag2_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag2_rb eq 0 ? 'background-color: 

lime':'background-color: pink'}">
<c:choose><c:when test="${(r.st4_vs6_bag2_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag2_rb) ne 0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.st4_vs6_bag2_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag2_rb)}" maxFractionDigits="2" 

minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${(r.st4_vs6_bag2_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag2_rb)}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>

<td scope="row" style="${r.st4_vs6_bag3_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag3_rb eq 0 ? 'background-color: 

lime':'background-color: pink'}">
<c:choose><c:when test="${((r.st4_vs6_bag3_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag3_rb)) ne 0}"> 
<fmt:formatNumber value="${(r.st4_vs6_bag3_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag3_rb)}" maxFractionDigits="2" 

minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
${(mm)}
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
${(r.st4_vs6_bag3_rb-row.st4_vs6_bag3_rb)}</c:otherwise></c:choose></td>




 <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page" />
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>


 </table>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this line

```
<%@ page import="comparision_list.Comaprision"%>
```

it is not used anyway